# Java: Threads won't ping at the same time

Tags: java, multithreading, echo, ping, icmp

I'm writing a simple network surviliance tool in Java. It basicly just has to ping a variable address range and save the answers in a database.

At first, I used the java.net library, but since it just uses an echo command, printers, routers and some servers in the network won't answer. So I used the [icmp4j](http://www.icmp4j.org/d/index.html) library.

Since it took about 10 to 15 minutes to ping an address range of 254, when doing it one by one, I decided to use threads to keep the scan time to a minimum. The problem however was, that it still pinged just one address at a time.

I've never worked with threads before, so here is the code, just in case I made a huge mistake:

```
//the AddressRange class just saves the current address and counts it up by one
    AddressRange ar = new AddressRange(tFStart.getText(), tFEnd.getText(), false);

    //next() checks, if the last address is reached and returns false, if that is the case
    while(ar.next()){
        try{
            //here, I create and start the threads
            new Thread(new Ping(ar.getAddress())).start();
        } catch (Exception f) {}

        //counts up the address by one
        ar.countUp(ar.getAddressBits());
    }
```

And here is my Ping class:

```
public class Ping implements Runnable{

private final String address;

public Ping(String address){
    this.address = address;
}
@Override
public void run() {

        IcmpPingRequest request = IcmpPingUtil.createIcmpPingRequest();
        request.setHost(address);

    try{            
        IcmpPingResponse response = IcmpPingUtil.executePingRequest(request);
        String formattedResponse = IcmpPingUtil.formatResponse(response);
        String output = "Destination: " + address + " \n" + formattedResponse + " \n";

        if(formattedResponse.contains("Reply")){
            InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(address);
            output += "Hostname: " + verifyHostName(addr.getHostName()) + " \n";
            System.out.println(output);
            saveClient(new PingData(output));
        }

    } catch (Exception f) {}
}
}
```

When I replaced the icmp4j- with the java.net library, the threads were processed at the same time. I've read, that threads should not access the same resources, so I guess, that's what happened here. But I'm way too unexperienced to analyse or even rewrite libraries.

Here is my Ping class without the usage of icmp4j:

```
public class Ping implements Runnable{

private final String address;

public Ping(String address){
    this.address = address;
}
@Override
public void run() {

    try{
        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(address);

        if(addr.isReachable()){
            String output += "Hostname: " + verifyHostName(addr.getHostName()) + " \n";
            System.out.println(output);
            saveClient(new PingData(output));
        }
    } catch (Exception f) {}
}
}
```

So I wanted to ask, if I made a mistake, or if someone has experience with said library and knows how to solve that problem or has a good alternative, which get's the job done.

Comment: Unrelated: `StringBuilder` is such a *core* class, it's even in the `java.lang` package. Writing your own class and calling it `StringBuilder` will really mess with anyone reading your code.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. I will correct it. :)

Comment: I just wrote the program to ping 140 IPs with multi threading & it is working fine for me with icmp4j library but as you also said, net library of java is giving unexpected results.  In less than a second, I got 100s of ping results. Are you getting any error or exception ? Debug it thoroughly by removing pinging steps one by one!!

Answer (score 1):

1. To answer your question of why the code pings 1 address only..

   ```
   while(ar.next()){
       try{
           //here, I create and start the threads
           new Thread(new Ping(ar.getAddress())).start();
   ```

   I suspect your `ar.getAddress()` always returns the same address, therefore you are just creating a bunch of threads pinging the same address.
2. It's not that threads couldn't access shared resource. You need to make sure the resource is thread safe.
3. What you are trying to do is to create a thread for each individual ping. This could be a bad practice especially when you have a lot of addresses, because 1)thread creation could cause overhead, and 2)having too many threads increases resource contention. A better way is to use ExecutorService. It manages a thread pool for you and all you have to do is to submit tasks (which is to ping an address)

Comment: the addresses are different, I'm sure about that. I will try the ExecutorService. Sounds like it could solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a huge number of threads will probably make performance worse.  The optimal number of threads depends on many factors, including how many CPUs/cores your OS allows the JVM to use, and whether the work the threads are doing is primarily CPU-bound or I/O-bound.  It's hard to even guess how many threads to use, but it's safe to say that 254 is way too many.

Instead of explicitly creating threads, feed `Runnable` tasks into a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).  That'll make it easy to play around with the number of threads.  You might even find that your OS network stack is the bottleneck, and using multiple threads gains you nothing at all.

Comment: I've already tested it with wireshark and until now, it just activated one ping command at a time. So it's hard to tell if the network stack is/will be the problem. The ThreadPoolExecutor sounds like a good idea, I definetly will give it a try. But since I'm not that fit in coding, it might take a while until I figured out how to use those java.util.concurrent libraries. But I will keep you updated, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

In icmp4j library, I noticed that only the assignment of the native bridge based on Operating System is made thread safe during initialization of Icmp4jUtil class while executing the ping request and the actual ping process execution is not made thread safe. So, there is no doubt that the threads cannot ping multiple address at the same time.It can ping multiple addresses.